# Custom Keyboard Shortcut to Launch IntelliJ Won't Work

Tags: shortcut-keys, 18.04, budgie, intellij

I've just installed *Ubuntu Budgie 18.04* and I'm trying to add a keyboard shortcut to launch **IntelliJ**.

I've created a new shortcut in the keyboard settings, and assigned <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to it.  The command I entered is `idea.sh` (I've tried it in quotes).  I've added the `/bin` to the path variable and can launch **IntelliJ** from any directory with that command in the terminal.  I replaced the command with `firefox` to make sure nothing was wrong and *Firefox* launched fine with the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> shortcut.

-UPDATE-
Another detail ,when I run idea.sh the shell pauses (no prompt for another command appears) until intellij is closed.  I created a ~/bin/idea script to run "idea.sh" and added it to the path.  I can now run intellij with just "idea".

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What's the result/output of the command `idea.sh` in a terminal? Does the shell interpreter find the command? What's the output of `which idea.sh`? FWIW my IntelliJ installation is accessible through the command `idea` but not `idea.sh` (although the former then invokes `/usr/share/jetbrains/intellij-idea/bin/idea.sh`).

Comment: The console outputs "Gtk-Message: 18:42:22.053: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module" and then intellij launches.

Comment: Also, The command line is unusable until intellij closes, which is not the case when I run another application opening command, like "firefox".  I created a /bin in my home directory and made an /idea script and exported that as the path so now I can just type "idea".  However,  it still doesn't work as a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: It's normal that the shell interpreter waits for commands to terminate unless you tell it otherwise. Again, what's the output of `which idea.sh`? If it's outside of the standard search paths the shortcut handler won't find it unless you specify its full path.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
which intellij-idea-educational
```

In Ubuntu 21.10 it outputs:

```
/snap/bin/intellij-idea-educational
```

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1223185)